# Возможно ли тут постановка тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Я уверен –– он не любит играть в компьютерные игры.

Знаю, что в таких предложениях тире заменяет сочинительный союз **что**.  Есть такое? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1)Я уверен, что он не любит играть в компьютерные игры. (2) Я уверен:  он не любит играть в компьютерные игры.  (3) Я уверен  – он не любит играть в компьютерные игры.

Это три варианта оформления одного сообщения: 1. СПП. 2. БСП, двоеточие. 3. БСП, тире.

Если мы используем БСП, то классическим знаком является двоеточие, которое соответствует изъяснительному значению второго предложения.

Тире в этом случае также можно использовать, при этом  варианты  «двоеточие/тире»  будут отличаться интонацией. Двоеточие соответствует увеличенной (предупредительной) паузе, а в случае тире пауза менее длительная, что более свойственно стилю речи в  этом сообщении.

Comment: Пожалуй, надо добавить еще один вариант: "Я уверен, он не любит играть в компьютерные игры". Здесь "Я уверен" - это ВВОДНОЕ СЛОВО в ПРОСТОМ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИИ, его можно переставлять, например: Он, я уверен, не любит играть в компьютерные игры". Тогда произношение беглое,  пауза только слегка обозначена.

Answer (score 2):

Если можно вставить союз "что", в таком случае ставится не тире, а двоеточие. Вот и здесь лучше всего поставить двоеточие, в крайнем случае - запятую

Comment: Тире тоже возможно, мне кажется.

Answer (score 0):

Следует поставить двоеточие.